# Рисование объектов Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

вопрос по opengl. Есть два квадрата , нужно разместить их на сцене так, чтобы один проткнул другой. Я вообще не представляю как надо это сделать, какие команды использовать.
Вот код:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <gl/GLAux.h>

unsigned int textures[2];

void LoadTextures()
{

 AUX_RGBImageRec *texture1 = auxDIBImageLoadA("фон2.bmp"), *texture2 = auxDIBImageLoadA("циф11.bmp");
 glGenTextures(2,&textures[0]);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, texture1->sizeX, texture1->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture1->data);

 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, texture2->sizeX, texture2->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture2->data);

}
int main(void)
{
 GLFWwindow* window;

 /* Initialize the library */
 if (!glfwInit())
     return -1;

 /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
 window = glfwCreateWindow(700, 700, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
 if (!window)
 {
     glfwTerminate();
     return -1;
 }

 /* Make the window's context current */
 glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

 /* Loop until the user closes the window */
 while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
 {

     LoadTextures();
     glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


     /* Render here */
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);

     glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
     glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);

     glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
     glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);

     glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
     glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);

     glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
     glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
     glEnd();


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
     glPushMatrix();
     glTranslatef(-0.3, 0.1, 0.0);
     glRotatef(-20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

     glNewList(1, GL_COMPILE_AND_EXECUTE);
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);// основная часть

     //основа
     glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
     glVertex2f(-0.25f, -0.25f);

     glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
     glVertex2f(-0.25f, 0.25f);

     glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
     glVertex2f(0.25f, 0.25f);

     glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
     glVertex2f(0.25f, -0.25f);

     glEnd();

     glEndList();

    glPopMatrix();

     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
     //2
     glPushMatrix();
     glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     glRotatef(20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
     glCallList(1);
     glPopMatrix();




     /* Swap front and back buffers */
     glfwSwapBuffers(window);

     /* Poll for and process events */
     glfwPollEvents();
 }

 glfwTerminate();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: В 2020 использовать glBegin / glEnd не стоит, даже для учебных целей. Это API старело уже десяток лет назад.

Comment: у нас универ в 1995 живет, так что приходиться